# SMS message is not present in inbox after receiving in Kitkat

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm creating little sms app, and after receiving it with my Broadcast receiver it is supposed to be present in inbox and it should be accessible to other sms apps as well, but it is not. It looks like no message was received at all. This issue occurs only when my app is default SMS app. Do I need to manually add received SMS to inbox after receiving it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do I need to manually add received SMS to inbox after receiving it?

Yes. The default SMS app is responsible for writing incoming messages to the Provider.

[Reference](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html?m=1)

Comment: From which version do I need to write to the provider? jelly bean?

Comment: No. The concept of a default SMS app wasn't introduced until KitKat, so prior to that things work "as usual".

Comment: I've read here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29 that when my app is default, I need to write to the provider whereas when I do, message is duplicated

Comment: This should be a new question, but I would guess that your Receiver is listening for the `SMS_RECEIVED` action as well, so it's getting called twice; once for that action, and once for the `SMS_DELIVER` action.

Comment: I had this issue but with received sms (notification was created twice) but i resolved it by checking action and calling it once. What I mean is that sent sms is added to the provider automatically despite my app is the default one (what should not happen according to documentation)